# How to locate a non-unique button on page using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am try to locate a button that does not have a unique identifier in the HTML.
I have tried eveyrthing and accessed multiple site on the web, I still cannot find a locator that works.
There are three buttons on the page, the one I need to lacate is the second one on the page. I have already tried;

```
element.all(by.css('[type="button"]')).get(1).click();

element.(by.xpathy('//div [@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]')).click();

$$('[ng-click="addAdminForm()"]').click();

element.all(by.css('.adminportal-submit-button')).get(0).click();
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="layout-align-start-center layout-row flex">

<button class="md-primary adminportal-cancel-button md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="gotoHomePage()" ng-disabled="disableButtons" analytics-on="" analytics-category="Clinics" analytics-event="cancel" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
</div>

<div class="layout-align-end-center layout-row">

<button class="md-raised md-primary adminportal-submit-button md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="addAdminForm()" ng-disabled="manageClinicForm.$invalid || disableButtons" analytics-on="" analytics-category="Clinic-Admins" analytics-event="register" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">

<button class="md-raised md-primary adminportal-submit-button md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="submit" ng-disabled="manageClinicForm.$invalid || disableButtons" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: can you try the below locator `$("button.adminportal-submit-button[type='submit']")`

Comment: If you can't use an ID, here's how we do it at work:

- Dummy CSS class. Call it anything that makes sense. It turns a styling mechanism into a purely-identification one (to me this is sort of an ID hack), but is generally the recommended way of going about it.

- Grab the smallest subset of elements you can (e.g. "button"), then use the index of the one that you want. Not ideal at all, a dummy CSS class is generally recommended over this. 

- If the button has a usefully identifiable label, iterate the buttons and use innerHTML to find it. 

One of those three usually does it.

Comment: I tried $("button.adminportal-submit-button[type='submit']") that did not work. I don't understand what a dummy CSS class is -- could you give me an example?

Comment: Tim Consolazio, could you post an example of what you mean by a Dummy CSS class?  Thanks TedR

Answer (score 0):

The locator by xpath, should work:

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]'))
```

If not then try to use waits:

```
var button = element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]'));
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]'))), 30000).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]'))), 30000).then(function () {
            browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-click="addAdminForm()"]'))), 30000).then(function () {
                button.click();
            });
        });
    });
```